# Checking value exist in a std::map - C++

Tags: c++, iterator, find, stdmap

I know *find* method finds the supplied key in *std::map* and return an iterator to the element. Is there anyway to find the value and get an iterator to the element? What I need to do is to check specified value exist in std::map. I have done this by looping all items in the map and comparing. But I wanted to know is there any better approach for this.

Here is what I have wrote

```
bool ContainsValue(Type_ value)
{
    bool found = false;
    Map_::iterator it = internalMap.begin(); // internalMap is std::map
    while(it != internalMap.end())
    {
        found = (it->second == value);
        if(found)
            break;
        ++it;
    }
    return found;
}
```

**Edit**

How about using another map internally which stores value,key combination. So I can call find on it? Is *find()* in std::map doing sequential search?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to create a [bidirectional map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html) - you can use either value of the pair as a key to do a quick lookup.

Answer (score 17):

If you have access to the excellent [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library then you should be using [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to create [bidirectional map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html) as Mark says. Unlike a std::map this allows you to look up by either the key or the value.

If you only have the STL to hand the following code will do the trick (templated to work with any kind of map where the mapped_type supports operator==):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
struct map_data_compare : public std::binary_function<typename T::value_type, 
                                                      typename T::mapped_type, 
                                                      bool>
{
public:
    bool operator() (typename T::value_type &pair, 
                     typename T::mapped_type i) const
    {
        return pair.second == i;
    }
};


int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> mapType;

    mapType map;

    map["a"] = 1;
    map["b"] = 2;
    map["c"] = 3;
    map["d"] = 4;
    map["e"] = 5;

    const int value = 3;

    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = std::find_if( map.begin(), map.end(), std::bind2nd(map_data_compare<mapType>(), value) );

    if ( it != map.end() )
    {
        assert( value == it->second);
        std::cout << "Found index:" << it->first << " for value:" << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Did not find index for value:" << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

> How about using another map internally which stores value,key combination. So I can call find on it?

Yes: maintain two maps, with one map using one type of key and the other using the other.

> Is find() in std::map doing sequential search?

No it's a binary search of a sorted tree: its speed is O(log(n)).

Comment: That makes sense. So will maintaining two maps give good performance than sequentially searching and finding value, right?

Comment: It will take twice as long to insert or delete anything (using two maps instead one); but for a large number of elements, finding will be a lot faster because O(log(n)) is much smaller than the O(n) that's needed for a sequential search.

Comment: So simple yet so good (especially when using the boost library isn't an option). Have my upvote.

I'd like to add that using `std::multimap` is probably better than `std::map` for the reversed map, because your original map can have duplicate values. Those duplicate values then become keys in the reversed map, so using `std::map` would lose data.

Answer (score 6):

Look into boost's bidirectional maps: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

It lets both values act like a key.

Otherwise, iteration is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

What you are requesting is precisely what [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) does  (not the member function)

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );
```

Comment: Great simple answer. Except it's not very efficient if done frequently.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to loop over the std::map and check all values manually. Depending on what you want to do, you could wrap the std::map in a simple class that also caches all of the values that are inserted into the map in something that's easily search-able and doesn't allow duplicates, like a std::set. Don't inherit from the std::map (it doesn't have a virtual destructor!), but wrap it so that you can do something like this:

```
WrappedMap my_map< std::string, double >;
my_map[ "key" ] = 99.0;
std::set< double > values = my_map.values(); // should give back a set with only 99.0 in it
```

An alternative to rolling your own would be to use the Boost bidirectional map, which is easily found in the posts below or by Google.

It really depends on what you want to do, how often you want to do it, and how hard it is to roll your own little wrapper class versus installing and using Boost. I love Boost, so that's a good way to go - but there's something nice and complete about making your own wrapper class. You have the advantage of understanding directly the complexity of operations, and you may not need the full reverse mapping of values => keys that's provided by the Boost bidirectional map.

Comment: He wants an iterator to the element, so you'd want to use a second map<> rather than a set<>.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very best option but might be useful in few cases where user is assigning default value like 0 or NULL at initialization.

```
Ex.
< int , string >
< string , int > 
< string , string > 

consider < string , string >
mymap["1st"]="first";
mymap["second"]="";
for (std::map<string,string>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
{
       if ( it->second =="" ) 
            continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer, if someone come here and looks for c++11 and above..

```
    //DECLARE A MAP
    std::map<int, int> testmap;

    //SAMPLE DATA
    testmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, 10));
    testmap.insert(std::make_pair(2, 20));
    testmap.insert(std::make_pair(3, 30));
    testmap.insert(std::make_pair(4, 20));

    //ELEMENTS WITH VALUE TO BE FOUND
    int value = 20;

    //RESULTS
    std::map<int, int> valuesMatching;

    //ONE STEP TO FIND ALL MATCHING MAP ELEMENTS
    std::copy_if(testmap.begin(), testmap.end(), std::inserter(valuesMatching, valuesMatching.end()), [value](const auto& v) {return v.second == value; });
```

Comment: Auto isn't available as a lambda parameter until C++14.

Comment: Yep. I agree. Modern cplusplus

Answer (score -4):

Possible that I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. But to simply test whether or not a map contains a value, I believe you can use the `std::map`'s built in `find`.

```
bool ContainsValue(Type_ value)
{
    return (internalMap.find(value) != internalMap.end());
}
```

Comment: `std::map::find` searches by key, he is trying to search by value.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I guess short of iterating and searching the map by hand, you should use a bidirectional map like the already suggested Boost.MultiIndex.