# Do not understand something about pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

So I did already manage to solve my problem but I have trouble understanding what exactly was the problem. My code before was:

```
BinaryTree removePrivate(int x, BinaryTree *node)
{
    if ((*node).m_key < x)
        *(*node).m_right = removePrivate(x, (*node).m_right);
    else if ((*node).m_key > x)
        *(*node).m_left = removePrivate(x, (*node).m_left);
    else
        node= NULL ;
    return *node;
}
```

It compiles just fine but things go to hell when it gets called.  Access violation at return *node;

I have changed it to:

[*]= * has been added, [ ]= * has been removed

```
BinaryTree [*]removePrivate(int x, BinaryTree *node)
{
    if ((*node).m_key < x)
        [ ](*node).m_right = removePrivate(x, (*node).m_right);
    else if ((*node).m_key > x)
        [ ](*node).m_left = removePrivate(x, (*node).m_left);
    else
        node= NULL ;
    return [ ]node;
}
```

Now everything works just fine but I am really not 100% sure why this is better.

Comment: As a service to the readers you might want to point out which lines differ exactly how.

Comment: In your old code, dereferencing a null pointer as you do with your `node` when it is `NULL` has undefined behaviour since you cannot dereference nothing.

Comment: Try to use `node->m_right` instead of `(*node).m_right` if possible it's more readable [why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263796/c-pointer-dereference-operator-vs).
Please also correct your spelling in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `(*node)`, you are dereferencing the pointer `node`. If you use `*(*node)`, as you originally had, you are dereferencing `(*node)`, which is the dereferenced  `node`. Thus, you are dereferencing twice, which does not make sense because `node` because points to a `BinaryTree` object, not another pointer.

In a simpler form:

```
*node = dereference node
*(*node) = dereference *node = dereference node twice
```