# How to check is there an element in map values

Tags: c++

There is a `map` with `map<string, vector<string>> buses;` structure, and I have a `string`, so I need to find out how to check `string` contains in `map` vector.

```
string stop;
cin >> stop;

if (buses.find(stop) != buses.end()) {
    cout << "Yes";
} else {
    cout << "No";
}
```

When I get a `stop` string I need to check is there in map's values (not keys, to be more precise in map.second) a string equals to `stop` string, if yes I need to print out all the keys containing `stop` element in values. `{ {"bus#1", {"stop#1", "stop#2", "stop#3"}}, ... }`

Comment: Do you mean "can I find out if there's a key in the map with a given string? If so `find` should do it. Can you give a complete example?

Comment: Can you please show the definition (and population) of `buses`?

Comment: @StephanLechner edited

Comment: @tadman no, I mean can I find a value in map's values not keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find mapped value of map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263640/find-mapped-value-of-map).

Comment: As far as I know there's no built-in method to search values, especially not if the values themselves are a nested container. Can you please re-write this code to be more complete, to show not only the actual data you're working with, but the result you expect?

Comment: @MaxVollmer I need to find among all the values of the map a `stop` element

Comment: I am sure his map is `{ {"bus#1", {"stop#1", "stop#2", "stop#3"}}, ... }`, so he need to first build a reverse map or make a lookup in a nested loop.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reverse your key-value pairs and use `find`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken, oh yeah, I think that's a solution, I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to loop over all map elements and then use `std::find` on the value vectors. This is really inefficient though.

Instead, you should use a `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` (or `std::unordered_multimap` if you don't need the sorting) and use the stops as key. Then add all buses that use said stop in that key and use `find` if you want to get all buses for that stop.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this is what you are trying to do.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, vector<string>> buses;

    buses["some stop"] = vector<string>();

    if (buses.find("some stop") != buses.end()) {
        cout << "Yes";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
}
```

Are you sure `map` is the data structure you want for this task?

Otherwise you may want to check out `std::set` if you only want to see if the stop is in the data structure.