# std::find_if , std::binary_function for searching std::map by value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

My `std::map` has pair of 'unique key' and 'unique value'. I usually find a key for a value and find a value for a key as well as.
I already know the method which by using `std::find_if` + lambda, however I want to know if there are any better ways.

After searching, I've found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535317/checking-value-exist-in-a-stdmap-c) and I've learned how to use `std::binary_function'.
Using both approach, I've checked 'elapsed time'.
This is my code.

```
typedef int                                 USER_ID;
typedef std::string                         USER_NICK_NAME;
typedef std::map<USER_ID, USER_NICK_NAME>   USER_MAP;

template<class T>
struct map_data_compare : public std::binary_function<typename T::value_type, typename T::mapped_type, bool>
{
  public:
  bool operator() (typename T::value_type &pair, typename T::mapped_type i) const
  {
    return pair.second == i;
  }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  USER_MAP user_map;
  string nick_prefix = "test";

  //make test map
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << i;
    user_map.insert(USER_MAP::value_type(i, nick_prefix + stream.str()));
  }

  const USER_NICK_NAME nick_name = "test99999";
  clock_t t;

  //Method 1 : using find_if + lambda
  cout << "Method 1 : using find_if + lambda" << endl;
  t = clock();
  auto it = std::find_if(user_map.begin(), user_map.end(), [&](const USER_MAP::value_type& user)
  {
    return nick_name == user.second;
  });
  if (it != user_map.end())
  {
    cout << "found nickname " << nick_name.c_str() << ", at index " << it->first << endl;
  }
  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "elapsed " << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

  cout << endl << endl;

  //Method 2 : using find_if + binary_function
  cout << "Method 2 : using using find_if + binary_function" << endl;
  t = clock();
  it = std::find_if(user_map.begin(), user_map.end(), std::bind2nd(map_data_compare<USER_MAP>(), nick_name));
  if (it != user_map.end())
  {
    cout << "found nickname " << nick_name.c_str() << ", at index " << it->first << endl;
  }
  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "elapsed " << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In my machine, **Method 1** is always faster than **Method2**. 
This is test result console.
[image]

So, My question is,

1. In my situation(I mean searching map by value), `find_if` + lambda is the best way?
   (Unfortunately, I can't use boost library.)
2. When I use `std::binary_function`?
3. I know that in C++ 11, `std::binary_function' has bee deprecated. Could I know the reason?

Thank you for your time to view this thread and for trying to help.

Comment: The reason for the deprecation of that and `std::bind2nd` is the fact that we have `std::function` and `std::bind` now.

Comment: You can use C++11 but not Boost? Interesting... `bimap` is perfect for you.

Comment: Do you have C++1y transparent operator based `set`/`map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my situation(I mean searching map by value), find_if + lambda is the best way?

It's certainly the neatest way (assuming you can't use a second map, or perhaps a boost-style multi-index map, to find values quickly). In principle, using an equivalent functor and/or `bind` shouldn't be significantly slower, the only difference here being that `nick_name` is captured by value rather than reference; perhaps you haven't enabled optimisations, or perhaps your compiler doesn't optimise `bind2nd` as well as one might hope.

> When I use `std::binary_function`?

Historically, you'd inherit from it to inject type aliases (`first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`) into your functor, if you didn't feel like defining them yourself. These were sometimes required, for example when using adapters like `bind2nd` (which are also deprecated) to create a new functor based on your one.

> I know that in C++ 11, `std::binary_function` has bee deprecated. Could I know the reason?

The types it defines are neither necessary or sufficient for the new-style variadic adapters  like `bind`, so it no longer does anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful for me. As you told, I disabled 'optimization'. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the C++1y feature of transparent comparisons, you can create a `std::set` of `std::map::iterator` that is sorted by the `.second` field, and make the comparator transparent so you can do lookups in it by the type of the `.second` field.

But that is unlikely.

If you do not have this, and you can make your value field (reasonably) cheap to copy, you can make a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` from the value field to iterators into the `std::map`.  This assumes you need both lookup *and* order in the main map.

If you do not need order, stop using `map`:

```
typedef std::unordered_map< int, std::string > main_map;
typedef std::unordered_map< std::string, int > backwards_map;
```

then wrap the above in some boilerplate to keep the two in sync.

Note that `unordered_map` iterators are non-persistent.  `std::map` iterators are highly persistent.  So the backwards map is different for the double-`unordered` case.

As for `binary_function` and `bind2nd`, it is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about 'transparent comparison', but I can't use them in 'C++ 11 + VS2010'. Am I correct? Thanks again.

Comment: @CodeDreamer VS2013 alpha test compiler *might* support it.  But no, 2010 does not.